# Timer Reset Button

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I have a timer that counts down from two minutes. What i need is a button that will stop and reset the timer. Here is the code i have.

js

```
$(function () {
var $startTimer = $('#startTimer');
var $timerDisplay = $('#timerDisplay');
var time = 120;

$timerDisplay.hide();

$startTimer.click(function () {
$startTimer.prop('disabled', true);
$timerDisplay.show();
var timeRemaining = time;
var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
var timeStamp = Math.floor(timeRemaining/60) + ':' +    timeRemaining%60;
$timerDisplay.text(timeStamp);
 if (timeRemaining === 0) {
 clearInterval(intervalId);
$timerDisplay.fadeOut();
alert('Time is up, please submit a vote :)');
$startTimer.prop('disabled', false);
} else {
timeRemaining--;
}
}, 1000);
});
});
```

HTML

```
  <div id="timerDisplay"></div>
  <button id="startTimer">Start Timer</button>
```

here is a working code pen of the timer but not the color change http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/RNomGG

Comment: So add a button, call clearInterval, reset the time, re-enable the start button.

Comment: how would i reset the time?

Comment: timeRemaining = time; to reset the time

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

**HTML:**

```
<div id="timerDisplay"></div>
<button id="startTimer">Start Timer</button>
<button id="stopTimer" disabled>Stop and Reset Timer</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    var $startTimer = $('#startTimer');
    var $stopTimer = $('#stopTimer');
    var $timerDisplay = $('#timerDisplay');
    var time = 120;
    var intervalId;

    $timerDisplay.hide();

    $startTimer.click(function () {
        $startTimer.prop('disabled', true);
        $stopTimer.prop('disabled', false);
        $timerDisplay.show();
        var timeRemaining = time;
        intervalId = setInterval(function () {
            var timeStamp = Math.floor(timeRemaining / 60) + ':' + timeRemaining % 60;
            $timerDisplay.text(timeStamp);
            if (timeRemaining === 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                $timerDisplay.fadeOut();
                alert('Time is up, please submit a vote :)');
                $startTimer.prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                timeRemaining--;
            }
        }, 1000);
    });

    $stopTimer.click(function() {
        time = 120;
        $startTimer.prop('disabled', false);
        $stopTimer.prop('disabled', true);
        $timerDisplay.hide();
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        $timerDisplay.text("");
    });
});
```

Basically, I moved the interval variable and created a stop timer button; the click functionality performs the reset, using the code similar to what you performed before.

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/w29ofkek/

Answer (score 0):

create a input button as follows

```
<input type='button' value="Stop" onclick="StopTimer();"/>
```

Change your code to following

```
var intervalId =null;
    $(function () {
    var $startTimer = $('#startTimer');
    var $timerDisplay = $('#timerDisplay');
    var time = 120;

    $timerDisplay.hide();

    $startTimer.click(function () {
    $startTimer.prop('disabled', true);
    $timerDisplay.show();
    var timeRemaining = time;
    intervalId = setInterval(function () {
    var timeStamp = Math.floor(timeRemaining/60) + ':' +    timeRemaining%60;
    $timerDisplay.text(timeStamp);
     if (timeRemaining === 0) {
     clearInterval(intervalId);
    $timerDisplay.fadeOut();
    alert('Time is up, please submit a vote :)');
    $startTimer.prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
    timeRemaining--;
    }
    }, 1000);
    });
    });

function StopTimer()
{
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```